# Why can't I locate the Android SDK?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Visual studio installation states that the SDK is installed:

[image]

However, I cannot find it anywhere. I searched all locations, including [this](http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/january/locating-android-sdk-for-xamarin-within-visual-studio.aspx) tutorial (there isn't even a folder named Android there). Anyway, any suggestions, what could be the issue? I clearly installed it manually.

Comment: so are you saying you opened up windows explorer and searched for "android-sdk" and result came back empty?

Comment: okay, I found the folder, but i cannot find adb.exe in it

Comment: `adb.exe` is inside `android-sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: there is no `platform-tools` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` folder

Comment: please search for `adb.exe` with the same method that you used earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download de SDK(NOT ANDROID STUDIO) Check the Image

[image]

Is in the bottom of this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)
Later just click install and next, next, and you have Android SDK, check where is the folder...